# Can not parse XML when getting Empty tag in xml

Tags: blackberry, xml-parsing

While parsing an XML in Blackberry using DOM i got an empty node like `</image>`.

while parsing is uses condition  if ("image".equals(node.getNodeName().toString())) to check whether this is image node or not. but does not get inside the condition.

if i uses xyz.jpg then image name returned. so please tell me condition by which i can classify whether this is empty node or not.

```
NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes(); 
int numChildren = childNodes.getLength();
Node firstChild = childNodes.item(0); 
if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { 
       if (numChildren == 1 && firstChild.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) { 
           if ("headline".equals(node.getNodeName().toString())) {
               vecHeadline.addElement(firstChild.getNodeValue()); 
           }
       }
}
```

but when i get empty tag like  this will not parse. actually i want to add a string where node is empty

Comment: What software/platform are you using to parse the xml?

Answer (score 1):

As you are not providing the exception I'll have to guess.
node.getNodeName().toString() is where it is crashing.

Try checking first is node.getNodeName() is not null